# JNI FindClass not finding class?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

When injecting this dll into a java program, the program immediately stops responding. When I open the debugger, it says the class I tried to find with env->FindClass is equal to 0x000000000000 (NULL). Can't figure out why since I'm certain the path given is correct...

Here's the code from my test project's MainThread:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <jni.h>

DWORD WINAPI Main_Thread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
HMODULE m_hDllInstance = LoadLibraryA("jvm.dll");
JavaVM *jvm;
JNIEnv *env;

typedef jint(JNICALL * GetCreatedJavaVMs)(JavaVM**, jsize, jsize*);

GetCreatedJavaVMs jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs = (GetCreatedJavaVMs)GetProcAddress(m_hDllInstance, "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs");

jint size = 1;
jint vmCount;

jint ret = jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs(&jvm, size, &vmCount);
jint rc = jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void **)& env, NULL);

//NULL?
jclass PlayerControllerMP = env->FindClass("net/minecraft/client/multiplayer/PlayerControllerMP"); //NULL?

jmethodID constructor = env->GetStaticMethodID(PlayerControllerMP, "<init>", "(Minecraft, NetHandlerPlayClient)PlayerControllerMP");

jobject pcmpObj = env->NewObject(PlayerControllerMP, constructor);
jmethodID getReach = env->GetMethodID(PlayerControllerMP, "getBlockReachDistance", "()F");

while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END))
{
    env->CallFloatMethod(pcmpObj, getReach);
}

jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
return S_OK;
}
```

Thanks for the help, sorry if code looks a little funny, had trouble pasting it in.

Comment: If you get an error from any JNI call you should use one of the exception-trace methods, and you should not let your code continue as though it hadn't happened.

Comment: You should not load jvm.dll, but rather use the instance that is already loaded: look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16254684/192373; also, make sure both jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs and AttachCurrentThread succeed before you proceed.

Comment: Check the class loader belonging to that thread