# How do I get a JavaVM or JNIEnv from an already-running JVM using JNI?

Tags: rust, java-native-interface, ffi, dll-injection, jnienv

I am working on a project which involves Rust and Java. I need to be able to use the JNI from the Rust side, without the Java side calling invoking it (because it is not my code). So far, I have been able to ensure my DLL is injected (open a small window on keypress, I have been using this for debugging).

A shortened example of the relevant code is the following:

```rs
use jni::sys::{JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs, JNIInvokeInterface_};


let jvm_ptr = null_mut() as *mut *mut *const JNIInvokeInterface_;
let count = null_mut();

// hasn't crashed

JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(jvm_ptr, 1, count);  // https://docs.rs/jni/latest/jni/sys/fn.JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs.html

// crashes
```

My question is this: is it possible to/how do I get a JNI environment in this situation?

Comment: Use [`AttachCurrentThread()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#AttachCurrentThread).

Comment: [Duplicate in another language](https://docs.rs/jni/latest/jni/sys/fn.JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs.html). `jvm_ptr` needs to point to a pre-allocated array of `JavaVM*` elements if you pass 1 as `bufLen`.

Comment: @user207421 That requires having a `JavaVM` pointer. Which is what OP is trying to retrieve. The opposite, [`get_java_vm`](https://docs.rs/jni/latest/jni/struct.JNIEnv.html#method.get_java_vm) might be relevant if this is in a callback. @Botje Did you by any chance paste the wrong link? (Lastly: documentation for the parameters of [`GetCreatedJavaVMs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs).)

Comment: @Caesar I did, derp. [Correct link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189049/get-all-instance-of-javavm-in-the-current-process)

Comment: @Caesar I do not have a `JNIEnv` either (so I can't call `get_java_vm`, as far as I know).

Comment: @Caesar That's not what he wrote. Last line of his question reads 'how do I get a JNI environment?' To which the answer is `AttachCurrentThread()`. And he is already calling `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs()`, so he already has a `JavaVM`.

Comment: @user207421 the point of the code shown was that `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs()` didn't work. (Or in this situation I wasn't using it right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the comments, I got that crash to stop happening. The trick was to pre-allocate an array.

```rs
let jvm_ptr = Vec::with_capacity(1).as_mut_ptr();
let count = null_mut();

JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(jvm_ptr, 1, count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't chunk a null pointer into the `vmBuf` parameter and then tell it that `vmBuf` points to an array of length 1 via `bufLen`. Translating the C++ code linked above, I would do something like

```rust
let mut count: jint = 0;
let check = JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(null_mut(), 0, &mut count);
assert!(check == JNI_OK);
let mut vms = vec![null_mut(); count as usize];
let check = JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(vms.as_mut_ptr(), vms.len() as i32, &mut count);
assert!(check == JNI_OK);
assert!(vms.len() == count as usize);
```

though that's probably a bit overkill since there can only be one VM. Still, checking the count is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this many years. It can be polished....

```
try {
     // how many JVMs is there?
     JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(NULL, 0, &number_of_JVMs);
 }
 catch (exception e)
 {
     int x = 0;
 }

 if (number_of_JVMs > 0)
 {
     JavaVM** buffer = new JavaVM * [number_of_JVMs];
     JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(buffer, number_of_JVMs, &number_of_JVMs); 
// 2. get the data
     jvm_handle = buffer[0];
     if (!jvm_handle == 0)
         return true;
     else return false;
 }
```